# How to ignore certificate in python 2.6?

Tags: python, ssl

In Python 2.7, I can do the below and it works:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context() // function does not exist in python 2.6 ?   What to use?
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
req =  urllib2.Request('https://myurl/')
```

The error I'm getting:

```
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_default_context'
```

How can I achieve the same effect in Python 2.6 as the function `create_default_context` does not exist there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have 2.6 install to test it, but I assume using the SSLContext constructor directly will work:

```
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.check_hostname = False

req =  urllib2.urlopen('https://myurl/', context=context)
```

Comment: got this `    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'`

Comment: Hm, as far as I can see, in Python 2.6 ssl/urllib2 does not verify the certificate. Do you get any errors with self-signed certificates if you just remove the whole context stuff?

Comment: Yes, in Python 2.6.4, with ssl/suds I don't need specific context change to connect to autofirmed https server (Cisco Call manager)

Comment: how this can we done in python 2.6 getting error : File "D:\Python26\lib\ssl.py", line 279, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host